# Signed curvature and turning angle

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to find the signed curvature of a function, I have so far that

$$g'(t)=(\cos(\cosh(t)), \sin(\cosh(t)))$$

I know that $g'$ is unit speed so i don't have to parametrize by arc length, and I know that the direction of $g'$ is measured by the angle $\phi$ such that $g'(t)=(\cos(\phi t), \sin(\phi t))$ but I'm unsure how to apply this here.

Comment: the implicit $g$ is an arc-parameterization because $||g'||=1$, so together with $g''$ you should be doing fine

Answer (score 0):

To find $x(t),y(t)$ one is compelled to solve this integrals:
$$x(t)=\int^t_0\cos(\cosh(u))du\quad
\mbox{and}\quad y(t)=\int^t_0\sin(\cosh(u))du,$$
but you don't need to.

Now, if we choose $g(t)=(x(t),y(t))$
we can compute the signed curvature with
$$k(t)=\frac{x'(t) y''(t) - y'(t) x''(t)}{(x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2)^{3/2}}.\qquad (*)$$

Since we already have $g'(t)$ it is remaining to compute $g''(t)$.

This is $g''(t)=(-\sin(\cosh(t))\sinh(t),\cos(\cosh(t))\sinh(t))$

Substituting  into $(*)$ then we are going to have 
$$k(t)=\sinh(t),$$
as the signed curvature for such a $g(t)$.

Comment: if we take advantage that $g$ is arc-parameterized then the unsigned curvature is just $\|g''\|$ which happens to be $\|\sinh(t)\|$

Comment: for the turning angle please tell me the definition